# Mobile Navigation Bar is only expanding on the home page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have basically the same navigation bar code on every page, but when its accessed on mobile i'm only able to expand the navigation bar on home.html , when i navigate to another page via the navigation bar i can no longer expand it.

Website: http://www.richardsongirlssoccer.com

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sjvroufr/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#navToggle a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $("header > nav").slideToggle();
    $("#logo").toggleClass("menuUp menuDown");
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    if($( window ).width() >= "600") {
        $("header > nav").css("display", "block");

        if($("#logo").attr('class') == "menuDown") {
            $("#logo").toggleClass("menuUp menuDown");
        }
    }
    else {
        $("header > nav").css("display", "none");
    }
});

$("header > nav > ul > li > a").click(function(e) {
    if($( window ).width() <= "600") {
        if($(this).siblings().size() > 0 ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).siblings().slideToggle("fast")
            $(this).children(".toggle").html($(this).children(".toggle").html() == 'close' ? 'expand' : 'close');
        }
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're missing some javascript includes on the other pages.

Specifically:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="navigationbar.js"></script>
```

Here's a picture of the source on your homepage:

[image: index.html]

And here's on another page (I believe schedule.html)

[image: schedule.html]

you need to include that javascript on all the pages, and it should work.

**EDIT**

Your fiddle wasn't working because you didn't include jQuery.  Here's a working copy of that too:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjvroufr/1/)